# Find whether a row in 2D array is empty and skip printing it

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a statement to check if a row of a 2D array contains an empty element?

This is related to homework. The restrictions are no libraries or lists or hashmaps or anything. I have a 2D string array, for instance {{"a","a","a"},{"b","","b"},{"c","c","c"}}. If I print it without checking anything, and some formatting I would get

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
a
a
a
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
b

b
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
c
c
c
```

I'm supposed to check whether the whole row has something empty and skip it if it is, so the correct output would be

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
a
a
a
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
c
c
c
```

I can check a single string `if(data[i][j] != null && !data[i][j].isEmpty())`, but is there a statement for rows?

The exception stuff is something else

```java
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] data = {{"a","a","a"},{"b","","b"},{"c","c","c"}};
    
        for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            try{
                if(/*row data[i] has no empty elements*/)
                    for (int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
                        System.out.println(data[i][j]);
                    }
                else
                    throw new EmptySpotException("Row("+i+"is missing elements, skipping line");
            } catch(EmptySpotException e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are no row operations for an array in Java. You need to check each element to see whether it contains an empty string or not.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check the full row for empty before printing.(or only blanks)

In order to do in one loop, row_output_string is constructed step by step and is print only is condition is false (skip).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{      
    String[][] data = {{"a","a","a"},{"b","","b"},{"c","c","c"}};
    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        
        boolean skip=false;
        //only to iterate once
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
        try{  
          //check for empty
          for (int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
              if(data[i][j].isBlank())
              {
                  skip=true;
                  throw new Exception("Row["+i+"]is missing elements, skipping line");
              }
              sb.append((j!=data[i].length-1) ? data[i][j]+"\n" :data[i][j]);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           //System.out.println("to be comment"+e.getMessage());
        };
        
        if(!skip)
        {
          System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
          System.out.println(sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Considering the termination of `try-block` when exception arise an enhancement could be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{      
    String[][] data = {{"a","a","a"},{"b","","b"},{"c","c","c"}};
    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        //only to iterate once
        StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer();
        try{  
          //check for empty
          for (int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
              if(data[i][j].isBlank())
              {
                  sb=null;
                  throw new Exception("Row["+i+"]is missing elements, skipping line");  
              }
              sb.append((j!=data[i].length-1) ? data[i][j]+"\n" :data[i][j]);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("to be comment"+e.getMessage());
        };
          
      if(sb!=null)
      {
          System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
          System.out.println(sb);
      }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output shows no output from an exception so I am excluding exception handling.  You can add that back in where you deem appropriate.

I would recommend using a labelled loop which is a normal part of Java and should meet your requirements.

- simply iterate thru the array of arrays as shown.
- then check each single array for an empty string.
- if the string is empty, continue to the next array via the outer loop
- otherwise print the appropriate output.

```
String[][] data = {{"a","a","a"},{"b","","b"},{"c","c","c"}};
next:
for(String[] arr : data) {
    for(String v : arr) {
        if (v.isEmpty()) {
            // empty element found so skip this array
            continue next;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    for (String v : arr) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

prints

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
a
a
a
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
c
c
c
```

Note:  Just like iterating over an array of `SomeType` from a single array (e.g. `for (SomeType s : arrayOfSomeType)`  You can also iterate over an array of array of SomeType the same way (`for(SomeType[] arr : arrayOfArrayOfSomeType)`. This can greatly simplify processing `"2D"` arrays as demonstrated above.